# How correct use try function to ignore any errors after loop executing in R

Tags: r

I have loop after which one, i have error
That's this loop.

```
> try(if (sum(staff[, 2] == 2) > 1) {

+   for (i in d_wrk) {

+     A[cur.row, which(shed.matrix[, 3] == i &

+                        shed.matrix[, 2] == 1)] <- 1

+     cur.row <- cur.row + 1

+   }

+   B[cur.pos:(cur.pos + 6 - cnt_d_off)] <- 1

+   dirs[cur.pos:(cur.pos + 6 - cnt_d_off)] <- '>='

+   cur.pos <- cur.pos + 7 - cnt_d_off

+ })
```

i've got the error

```
Error in [<-(*tmp*, cur.row, which(shed.matrix[, 3] == i & shed.matrix[,  :

  subscript out of bounds
```

this error does not matter for me, it can and should be ignored, but because of it, the script stops and stops working to the end.

I started looking for how to ignore the error and found the `try` function, only when I do such a syntax as in my example, it does not work. What is the correct way to ignore the error if it appears using `try` functon?
If I gave too little information, just let me know, there are three matrices working here (staff, A, B). I do not think that they need to be reproduced.I just want to figure out what use correct syntax to the loop with `try`. I think i do something wrong.
Any help is appreciated for me, thanks.

Comment: You could check `?try`, especiall the part *"If an error occurs then the error message is printed to the stderr connection unless options("show.error.messages") is false or the call includes silent = TRUE. "*  -> For your case that could be: `print("A");
try(a <- thisfails, silent=TRUE);
print("B")
`

Comment: Switching off error messages is often a last resort and can lead to much worse problems later on. In your case, it seems like a simple range check would get rid of the errors. For example, inside your loop you could first do `colnum <- which(shed.matrix[, 3] == i & shed.matrix[, 2] == 1)`. Then `if(length(colnum) < 1 | any(colnum > ncol(A))) continue`. This should explicitly avoid the specific error you are happy to ignore but will not run the risk of ignoring all other important errors that the code might throw up. In short, don't ignore errors - avoid them.

Comment: @dario yes i got it

Comment: @AllanCameron thanx, it was good idea too